# Dart any dependency usage in pubspec.yaml for multi module project

Tags: flutter, dart

I need something similar in Dart to what `Maven` has with a `parent-pom` `dependencyManagement` structure.

I have 2 modules in Dart, `api` and `core`.

`api/pubspec.yaml`:

```
...
dependencies:
  http: '>=0.12.0 <0.13.0'
  meta: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
...
```

`core/pubspec.yaml`:

```
...
dependencies:
  api:
    path: ../api
  # Meta is added again with a version number
  meta: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
  redux: '4.0.0'
...
```

So if I change the dependencies in `core/pubspec.yaml` to `'any'` if they already exist in `api/pubspec.yaml`:

```
...
dependencies:
  api:
    path: ../api
  # No version number is needed, the exact version will come from the dependency
  meta: 'any'
  redux: '4.0.0'
...
```

This seems to be working, but the [official site](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#traditional-syntax) does not mention this feature, instead:

> The string any allows any version. This is equivalent to an empty version constraint, but is more explicit. **Although** `any` **is allowed, we don’t recommend it**.

Is this an unintended good use case of the `'any'` or this is a bad idea? (I am confident `api` dependency will always exist and declare `meta`, they are all my modules.)